# What responsibility did Golda Meir have for the Yom Kippur war?

Tags: middle-east, israel, diplomacy, egypt, diplomatic-history

I read in the book "The Iron Wall" by Avi Shlaim,  there was a description of the Yom Kippur war that happened due to Golda Meir's insistence on keeping parts of Sinai and not trading them to Egypt for peace.
In a chapter called "Immobilization" in the authors book, it was described in the end, that Meir was given a similar peace agreement to what Menachem Begin was given (At Begin's time, a peace agreement was signed that related to the return of Sinai to Egypt for peace between the countries).
It was also described that it was Meir's fault for not accepting the agreement, a situation which later on led to a war.

How much evidence is there that supports or opposes Meir's failure in diplomacy/politics to achieve peace with Egypt and prevent the Yom Kippur war?

Comment: I personally agree, as it conforms with how I was taught (and obviously intelligence failings allowed the war to be a near-catastrophe but wouldn't **cause** a war in and of itself) But I feel that the question as stated is a bit opinion-based/hypothetical, since Egypt was **just one** participant on the Arab side of the war. Perhaps you might consider rephrasing to focus on whether Golda Meir was presented with Egyptian peace offers?

Comment: At the time of the Camp David Accords being reached, the opinion of the pundits was that only Menachem Begin could have ever signed such a deal, by virtue of not having Menachem Begin as Leader of the Opposition to scuttle it.

Comment: Note that it was and is not within the scope of Israeli executive powers for a Prime Minister to unilaterally sign a peace accord; any such agreement must be approved by the Knesset: http://www.thecrimson.com/article/1978/9/28/israeli-parliament-approves-camp-david-peace/. Note also that a side effect of the Yom Kippur war was that the Israeli military began to perceive the Egyptian Armed Forces as being competent, an opinion that did not exist in, for example, 1967. This also affected civilian opinion of the Accord within Israel.

Comment: I read your comments. I just want to add that, the chapter in the book. Described the passiveness and the stubborness that she showed towards the concessions and piece negotiations towards Egypt. Meir was described as a politician that shared Ben-Gurions mentality of keeping the land "at all costs". Her politics overall and not a single act lead to failure of any peace negotiation failure and the break of the yum kipur war. The bottom line is that she didnt want to give up Sinai, and that caused the war..

Comment: You may want to read some criticism of Shlaim (and that specific book) before deciding to use it as your Bible. He basically cherry picked the facts to suit his ideology. e.g. [1](http://muse.jhu.edu/journals/shofar/summary/v019/19.4karsh.html), [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avi_Shlaim#Criticism)

Comment: This question needs a lot of work.  It postulates dubious counterfactuals as the basis for asking about real history, and the question itself is "how much evidence".  Any answer would necessarily be "some."

Comment: Israel was attacked because it existed, and because there's Jews living there. THAT is all the reasons the Arabs needed. The Sinai might have been something for them to use as justification to the world community, but nothing else.

Comment: @jwenting, I really doubt that you are right.

Comment: I added some tags, hope you don't mind.

Comment: The question assumes that Nasser or Sadat, prior to 1973, would have been willing to trade Sinai for peace, or even offered it.  Do you have evidence that he actually did make the offer?  To whom?  When?  When Sadat finally visited Israel in 1979, Meir said to Sadat:  "what took you so long?"  Her question implied that he had never made an offer for peace.  He did not say she was wrong then, or ever, as far as I know.  As far as the book's hypothesis --Israeli book stores, unlike those in Egypt, are filled with books critical of the government for one thing or another.

Comment: The more common question against Meir is whether she had reason to know that Egypt and Syria intended to attack, and why she didn't mobilize the reserves before Yom Kippur.

Comment: @XWorm you'd then be surprised to hear I am indeed right. The Arabs were and still are determined to eradicate Israel from the face of the earth, and as many (preferably all) Jews while they're at it. That's the sole purpose for which Hamas, PLO, Hezbollah, and a host of other terrorist groups were created by them, and the sole purpose they repeatedly invaded Israel. Only reason they've not done so recently is Israel possessing nuclear weapons and not being afraid to use them when its existence is threatened (iow, they'll take Damascus, Cairo, Aman, Baghdad, and maybe others with them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are referring to a proposal by Moshe Dayan to Meir in December 1970 that Israel withdraw 20 miles from the Suez Canal in order to aid the Egyptians in reopening the canal and possibly averting their motivation to go to war, according to [this article](http://www.timesofisrael.com/three-years-too-late-golda-meir-understood-how-war-could-have-been-avoided/#!) in the Times of Israel.  Two months later, Sadat, in a speech to the Egyptian National Assembly adopted Meir's proposal, but his proposal did not include recognition of Israel or a willingness to negotiate and agree on border, two items that were fundamental Israeli demands, and things that Sadat ultimately agreed to with Begin.  Moreover, the article asserts that Israel was advised by the Nixon administration not to agree to Sadat's proposal without further conciliatory gestures from Sadat.

In 2013, the Israeli government [released documents](http://www.archives.gov.il/NR/exeres/AB6D1490-0846-4573-A380-3BE0D7EE2279,frameless.htm?NRMODE=Published) that in early June 1973, Israel sent Sadat a secret message through West German Chancellor Willy Brandt, proposing that Israel would be willing secretly meet with Sadat to trade Sinai to Egypt for peace.  In a later meeting she described the offer, saying: "He can tell Sadat that he, Brandt, is convinced that we truly want peace. That we don’t want all of Sinai, or half of Sinai, or the major part of Sinai. Brandt can make it clear to Sadat that we do not request that he begin negotiations in public, and that we are prepared to begin secret negotiations, etc."  For the original Hebrew-language document, see [Document 8](http://www.archives.gov.il/NR/rdonlyres/D801FE51-5FEE-4DF8-BC1E-84BDDE972ED3/0/Brandt08.pdf).

Coming so closely after the 1972 Munich massacre of Israeli atheletes, Brandt was not so willing to involve West Germany in the negotiations at a high level.  He sent a relatively low-level diplomat to meet with Egyptian officials.  According to a 2013 Times of Israel [article](http://www.timesofisrael.com/golda-meir-offered-egypt-part-of-sinai-for-peace/), Hafiz Ismail, a close adviser to Egyptian president Anwar Sadat, and relayed the Israeli proposal, advised Sadat to reject the offer on the basis that unless Israel was willing to retreat to the pre-1967 cease-fire lines, there was no point in talking directly with the Jewish state.

Meir's disappointment with Sadat's failure to accept her offer to meet was reflected in her first comment to him when they met on his first visit to Israel in 1977, where she said simply, "what took you so long?"  Hinn, Benny, [Blood in the Sand](https://books.google.com/books?id=N8EkoTfwSAoC&pg=PT164&lpg=PT164&dq=Golda%20Meir%20%22what%20took%20you%20so%20long?%22&source=bl&ots=1bKsgsjlXr&sig=DpYNahZ05RK2MCS4QNVCC2gmt9U&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ohybVJnoAdP4yQSl2YHACQ&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Golda%20Meir%20%22what%20took%20you%20so%20long%3F%22&f=false), p. 150.

Comment: Whenever Israel is defended here, some anonymous person will down vote no matter how well documented the answer is.

Comment: The argument is a bit flimsy with all that low level negotiations. ...hmmmm .. I

Comment: Nice articles, interesting to see that there is some argument with evidence against what Avi Shlaim wrote.